# GLightbox video gallery with local video

Tags: javascript, gallery

I'm using GLightbox on https://biati-digital.github.io/glightbox/, is there a way to make gallery for videos on my server, with m3u8 type. And the link is get it after gallery is opened "HTML5 videos"
all that in JavaScript.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.